# SAPUI5 why is the global BusyIndicator hiding too early?

Tags: sapui5, busyindicator

I've shown my BusyIndicator in the routeMatched() function

```
sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.show();
```

Later on, this is hidden after I set the page to visible again.

```
...
...
... 

    self.getView().byId("Page1").setVisible(true);
    sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();
```

The issue is:  Because the view is shown again soon after, the indicator is hidden again, however, on a slower mobile, the page is in the process of rendering AFTER hiding the Indicator.

I need the view completely hidden until it's finished loading..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is loading data before rendering, hide the `busyIndicator` in the success method of your AJAX requests.

If you are using oData Model, attach a listener to the `batchRequestCompleted` event of the oData Model and hide the `BusyIndicator` when the event is fired.

This should optimize the behavior on a mobile device.
Because of the asynchronous behavior of the SAPUI5 framework of rendering elements depending on the received data, it can be that some UI elements are still rendering, although the page is already visible.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use sap.m.busyIndicator as opposed to sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.